# Add element to immutable vector rust

Tags: recursion, vector, rust, functional-programming, immutability

I am trying to create a user input validation function in rust utilising functional programming and recursion. How can I return an immutable vector with one element concatenated onto the end?

```rust
fn get_user_input(output_vec: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    // Some code that has two variables: repeat(bool) and new_element(String)
    if !repeat {
        return output_vec.add_to_end(new_element); // What function could "add_to_end" be?
    }
    get_user_input(output_vec.add_to_end(new_element)) // What function could "add_to_end" be?
}
```

There are functions for everything else:
`push` adds a mutable vector to a mutable vector
`append` adds an element to the end of a mutable vector
`concat` adds an immutable vector to an immutable vector
`???` adds an element to the end of a immutable vector

The only solution I have been able to get working is using:

```rust
[write_data, vec![new_element]].concat()
```

but this seems inefficient as I'm making a new vector for just one element (so the size is known at compile time).

Comment: Why can't you just take `mut output_vec: Vec<String>`? What's the possible reason you _couldn't_ take the value mutably? (Or is `output_vec` supposed to be a reference?)

Comment: I _could_ make it mutable but I would like a way of doing this adhering to the principles of functional programming.

Comment: Is `add_to_end` supposed to return a new `Vec`? It seems like it would effectively be `let mut result = output_vec.clone(); result.push(new_element)`

Comment: @Alex You are already trying to use the equivalent of `Vec::push()` in your example code, which is not purely functional. You will find that a pure functional approach doesn't work well in rust due to its borrow system. Additionally, note that, unlike languages like JavaScript or Java where you never actually own an object (rather, you always have a reference), in Rust you can own an object _itself_, which is what `output_vec` is. You don't have to worry about not mutating objects that don't belong to you because `output_vec` _does belong to this function_ since it is taken by value.

Comment: @Herohtar That would be redundant in this code because `output_vec` is already owned by the function, and will be destroyed/moved when it returns. There is no reason whatsoever to make a copy of the argument.

Comment: You can't modify it because it's immutable, so the only option you have is to make a mutable copy and modify that, or else append together two immutable things. Either way, the end result is allocating new memory.

Comment: @Herohtar No, you can make the argument `mut` which does neither of those things.

Comment: @cdhowie Right, that's the obvious solution, but OP is wanting to leave it immutable; I'm saying those are the only options given that constraint.

Comment: Right, I'm questioning the reasoning behind the constraint because I don't think it's a useful constraint, and belies a misunderstanding of ownership in Rust.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are confusing Rust with a language where you only ever have references to objects. In Rust, code can have exclusive ownership of objects, and so you don't need to be as careful about mutating an object that *could* be shared, because you *know* whether or not the object is shared.

For example, this is valid JavaScript code:

```
const a = [];
a.push(1);
```

This works because `a` does not contain an array, it contains a *reference to an array.*<sup>1</sup>  The `const` prevents `a` from being repointed to a different object, but it does *not* make the array itself immutable.

So, in these kinds of languages, pure functional programming tries to avoid mutating any state whatsoever, such as pushing an item onto an array that is taken as an argument:

```
function add_element(arr) {
  arr.push(1); // Bad! We mutated the array we have a reference to!
}
```

Instead, we do things like this:

```
function add_element(arr) {
  return [...arr, 1]; // Good! We leave the original data alone.
}
```

What you have in Rust, given your function signature, is a *totally different scenario!*  In your case, `output_vec` is owned by the function itself, and no other entity in the program has access to it.  There is therefore *no reason* to avoid mutating it, if that is your goal:

```
fn get_user_input(mut output_vec: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
//       Add mut  ^^^
```

You have to keep in mind that any non-reference is an owned value. `&Vec<String>` would be an immutable reference to a vector something else owns, but `Vec<String>` is a vector this code owns and nobody else has access to.

Don't believe me?  Here's a simple example of broken code that demonstrates this:

```
fn take_my_vec(y: Vec<String>) { }

fn main() {
    let mut x = Vec::<String>::new();
    
    x.push("foo".to_string());
    
    take_my_vec(x);
    
    println!("{}", x.len()); // E0382
}
```

The expression `x.len()` causes a compile-time error, because the vector `x` was *moved* into the function argument and we don't own it anymore.

So why shouldn't the function mutate the vector it owns now? The caller can't use it anymore.

---

In summary, functional programming looks a bit different in Rust.  In other languages that have no way to communicate "I'm giving you this object" you must avoid mutating values you are given because the caller may not expect you to change them.  In Rust, who owns a value is clear, and the argument reflects that:

- Is the argument a value (`Vec<String>`)?  The function owns the value now, the caller gave it away and can't use it anymore.  Mutate it if you need to.
- Is the argument an immutable reference (`&Vec<String>`)?  The function doesn't own it, and it can't mutate it anyway because Rust won't allow it.  You could clone it and mutate the clone.
- Is the argument a mutable reference (`&mut Vec<String>`)?  The caller must explicitly give the function a mutable reference and is therefore giving the function permission to mutate it -- but the function still doesn't own the value.  The function can mutate it, clone it, or both -- it depends what the function is supposed to do.

If you take an argument by value, there is very little reason not to make it `mut` if you need to change it for whatever reason.  Note that this detail (mutability of function arguments) isn't even part of the function's public signature simply because it's not the caller's business. They gave the object away.

---

Note that with types that have type arguments (like `Vec`) other expressions of ownership are possible.  Here are a few examples (this is not an exhaustive list):

- `Vec<&String>`: You now own a vector, but you don't own the `String` objects that it contains references to.
- `&Vec<&String>`: You are given read-only access to a vector of string references.  You could clone this vector, but you still couldn't change the strings, just rearrange them, for example.
- `&Vec<&mut String>`: You are given read-only access to a vector of *mutable* string references.  You can't rearrange the strings, but you can change the strings themselves.
- `&mut Vec<&String>`: Like the above but opposite: you are allowed to rearrange the string references but you can't change the strings.

---

<sup>1</sup> A good way to think of it is that non-primitive values in JavaScript are always a value of `Rc<RefCell<T>>`, so you're passing around a handle to the object with interior mutability. `const` only makes the `Rc<>` immutable.

Comment: If a list or an array is passed to a function as a value, how can the calling function stop owning it? Is there just implicit cloning taking place?

Comment: @IvenMarquardt No, the value is moved into the function argument and the caller ceases to own it. The value will be destroyed when the function returns unless it is moved somewhere else (such as by being returned). In my example code, after the call to `take_my_vec(x)`, the local variable `x` could be thought of as "uninitialized" again. (Since `x` is `mut`, you could assign another vector to it and then use the variable again, but the vector that used to be in `x` was transferred to the function argument.)

Comment: @IvenMarquardt There is a built-in function `std::mem::drop()`. The purpose of this function is to destroy a value that you don't need anymore, freeing any memory allocations or other resources (file/network handles, etc.) that might be associated with it. How does it do this? The definition of this function is literally `pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }`. There's no magic here -- the value is destroyed because you move it to a function argument, and the function immediately returns, destroying the value since it's now the owner and the owning variable is going out of scope.

Comment: @cdhowie I wish I could give 20 Upvotes to this elaboration! Fantastic! Thanks a ton.